# How to show an alert when we click on url or phone number in textview?

Tags: android

I have a text view which will contain link or the phone number. On click on the link its directly redirecting to default browser, but i want to throw a dialog box asking user whether they want to be redirected to browser or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
//This is onClick method of textview
public void textViewOnClick(View v) {    
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Do u want to redirect to the browser?");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //redirect to the browser
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("cancel", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Actually My textview will have both normal words and links. Alert box has to be triggered only when we click on the URL link inside the textview. I am really sorry i think i am not clear with my question earlier.